# Does Javascript template Strings work inside Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm trying to dynamically change image source in javascript inside a Django templates file as follows

```
image.src = `{{ static('images/Principle_Icon/Principle${index+1}.svg')}}`;
console.log(`{{ static('images/Principle_Icon/Principle${index+1}.svg')}}`)
```

but this doesn't seem to work since this is what I'm getting

```
/static/images/Principle_Icon/Principle%24%7Bindex%2B1%7D.svg
```

should I expect the javascript template string to work inside django templates?

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar issue. I checked the developer code and seems like JavaScript wraps Django template tags in a separate strings thereby rendering the tags as literal strings instead.